# How to pass a variable into a input value on page load?

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events

The input field is not printing the value generated from the function domainRef.

Here is my code :

```
<div id="divref" onpageshow="domainRef()">

<script>
function domainRef(){
var ref = document.referrer.toString();
 document.getElementById("test").value = ref ;
}                          
</script>
</div> 

<input type="hidden" id="test" value="">
```

Comment: Probably executing before the DOM has finished rendering. Try using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<div id="divref"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="">
<script>
  domainRef();
  function domainRef(){
    var ref = document.referrer.toString();
    document.getElementById("test").value = ref ;
  }                          
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
<div id="divref">
  <script>
    window.onload = domainRef;

    function domainRef() {
      var ref = document.referrer.toString();
      document.getElementById("test").value = ref;
    }
  </script>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="">
```

The problem is that most likely the DOM has not been fully loaded when the`onpageshow` event is triggered. A similar solution is to trigger the function using the `onload` event attribute on the body element.

```
<body onload=domainRef()>
  <div id="divref">
    <script>
      function domainRef() {
        var ref = document.referrer.toString();
        document.getElementById("test").value = ref;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="test" value="">
</body>
```

For the latter solution I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WittigMarcus/0vb18wag/) where I have removed the hidden attribute to show the input field with the resulting value.

Comment: The returning value is empty... i tried with <div id="divref" onload="domainRef()">... but it is the same !

Comment: You need to place the event attribute on the body element! The body must be fully loaded!

Comment: Now, I have also added a JsFiddle for demo

Comment: Btw, it also works if you use `onpageshow` instead of `onload`. The essential bit is that it must be applied on the body element in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the example on JsFiddle !